# What is managed object context?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

What does it mean **managed object** in Core Data? Why the object is in **context**? What's the meaning of **object**, and what is **context** here?

When I create managed object context, can it carry 'FetchRequest's from **multiple entities** in data?

Answer (score 1):

Read this article:

[Core Data Overview](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-overview/)

The NSManagedObjectContext is an `abstraction` so you can talk to Core Data, where the DB is handled on the background.

Comment: Thanks for article! I don't understand if 'object' means one 'entity', or all the 'entities' ?

Comment: @MikeMaus Object refers to all NSManagedObjects (Entities), this is a class that Core Data talks to, hence all your Entities inherit from the same class;
Now in the article I sent you, you can see in the diagrams, NSManagedObject, in that **array**, represented by the box, live all your entities, say one **Note** entity, and two **Record** entities.